# iOS Swift Only run on the main thread error for app

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard

I am new to swift and I have a login page that takes the users credentials and check if it's the right credentials . I think return the response in JSON if it's the right credentials then I try to go to a new ViewController  .I got this error when I try to go to a new View Controller, I have this in a closure so I do not know why I am getting this issue. This is my code

```
func LoginClosure(completion:@escaping (Bool) ->Void) {
    var check = 0
    let url:URL = URL(string:ConnectionString+"login")!

    if submitEmail == nil || submitPassword == nil {
        submitEmail = email.text!
        submitPassword = password.text!
    }

    let session = URLSession.shared
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let parameter = "Email=\(submitEmail!)&password=\(submitPassword!)"
    request.httpBody = parameter.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        session.dataTask(with:request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                // print(error)
            } else {
                do {
                    let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:Any]

                    if let Streams = parsedData?["Profile"] as? [AnyObject]  {
                        // check for misspelled words
                        for Stream in Streams {
                            if let rr = Stream["result"] as? Bool {
                                self.result = rr
                            } else {
                                self.result = true
                            }

                            if let id = Stream["id"] as? Int {
                                self.defaults.setValue(id, forKey: "my_id")
                                // Success
                                MYID = id
                                completion(true)
                                return
                            }
                        }

                        if check == 0 {
                            // Bad credentials
                            completion(false)
                        }
                    }
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }).resume()
    }
}
```

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Only run on the main
>   thread!'

That error occurs with this line:

```
let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AccountC") as! AccountC
self.present(next, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: It looks like `completion(true)` isn't been called from the main thread

Comment: You really should not be using `DispatchQueue.main.async` to call `session.dataTask`. Doing so does not it any way affect where the task's completion handler is called.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> As per apple standards, you have to perform UI activity in the main queue only.

Just call your closure in the `main queue` as below.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    completion(true)
}
```

You can also perform only UI changes in the `main queue` as below.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AccountC") as! AccountC
    self.present(next, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

@rmaddy Thanks for the valuable suggestion.

Comment: I think it is better to put the use of `DispatchQueue.main.async` inside the completion block itself. It is the code in the completion block that knows if any of its code should be run on the main queue or not.

Comment: I think you are right, But  for above answer it is working fine becuase we are performed only UI related activity after calling completion block.

Comment: Yes, this answer works but my point is that the code that calls the completion handler should make assumption about any particular queue. Let the actual completion block make that decision.

Comment: @rmaddy Please check updated answer. Thanks a lots for valuable contribution. Cheers...

Answer (score 2):

In your code, I see that you have initiated the network call in the main queue. That makes sure that creation of the data task and starting it off will be performed on the main thread. But it doesn't guarantee that the completion closure will also be called on the main thread.

Therefore I would suggest removing the network call from the `DispatchQueue.main.async` block. Then please execute the code that performs UI updation in a `DispatchQueue.main.async block` as follows.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {    
    let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AccountC") as! AccountC
    self.present(next, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```